# NodeJS Var Undefining itself?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Simple Question: Why on earth is this undefining itself!?

```
const bot = new TelegramBot(config.ttoken, {
  polling: true
});
console.log(bot) // WORKING AND DEFINED
con.query(`SELECT * FROM user WHERE token = "${token}"`, (err, rows) => {
     if (err) throw err;
     rows.forEach((row) => {
          console.log(bot) // NOT WORKING AND UNDEFINED?
     )}
});
```

why....

Comment: There must be something else going on besides this exact code because what you show would not actually happen if this was the only code there was in this exact order in one file.

Comment: Thats really all there is, i removed some stuff that i know for 100% would not have an affect.
Stuff like console logs and junk.

This really is all the important bits.

Comment: Nope.  Some of what you think is unimportant is messing things up.  It could even be some brackets that aren't correct or something like that.  Variables, particularly `const` variables don't just have their values disappear.  The most likely cause is that you are redefining `bot` in some containing function and you're looking at a different copy of the variable than what you want to be looking at.  Please post ALL the code.

Comment: I dont think i can post the whole thing its over 5300 lines...
Ive checked the entire thing and bot is never even touched

Comment: Well, we can't help you without seeing the lines of code in this module that come before this because that's where something is messing you up.  I've told you what my guess is, but that's all I can do without seeing actual code.

Comment: Another possibility is that one of these pieces of code is inside some asynchronous callback so the timing of execution isn't what you think it is.  But, I'm not going to spend any more time doing blind guesses.  If you want any further help from me, you have to show the actual code.  Otherwise, you can wait for someone else to try to make guesses.  But, stackoverflow isn't supposed to be about guessing.